# Closing a DIV will closing another related input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several .tab classes `<span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>` `<span class="tab">Close Tab2</span>` `<span class="tab">Close Tab...</span>`.  I also have inputs.  What .tab and input relationship is `<span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>` and `<input name="Close Tab1" placeholder="Close Tab1">`

**Goal:** When I click on Close Tab1 (red square), this tab will be hidden also input Close Tab1 will be hidden, too.

Please take a look at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrk837uz/1/) give a hand.

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
 $(this).hide();
  if($('.tab').is(':visible') == false) {
   $('.message').show();
  }
  
  var MainTabName = $('#main-tabs input').attr('name');
  var bannerTab = $('.tab:contains('+MainTabName+')');
  
})
```

```css
#banner-message {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}
.tab {
  
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px
}
.message {
  display: none;
}
#main-tabs {
  display: grid;
}
input {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="message">
  This is a banner message
  </span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab1</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab2</span>
  <span class="tab">Close Tab3</span>
</div>

<p>
<div id="main-tabs">
  <input name="Close Tab1" placeholder="Close Tab1">
  <input name="Close Tab2" placeholder="Close Tab2">
  <input name="Close Tab3" placeholder="Close Tab3">
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic objective is to define some kind of relationship where the tab knows which input is associated with it. There are quite a few ways you could do this. Here is just one, taking advantange of data-attributes - the tab has a data-attribute whose value matches the ID of the input. You can then use that to form a selector in order to hide the input.

```js
$('.tab').click(function() {
  var tab = $(this);
  tab.hide();
  $("#" + tab.data("input")).hide();
  
  if ($('.tab').is(':visible') == false) {
    $('.message').show();
  }

  var MainTabName = $('#main-tabs input').attr('name');
  var bannerTab = $('.tab:contains(' + MainTabName + ')');
});
```

```css
#banner-message {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 42px;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

.tab {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.message {
  display: none;
}

#main-tabs {
  display: grid;
}

input {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <span class="message">
  This is a banner message
  </span>
  <span class="tab" data-input="input1">Close Tab1</span>
  <span class="tab" data-input="input2">Close Tab2</span>
  <span class="tab" data-input="input3">Close Tab3</span>
</div>

<p>
  <div id="main-tabs">
    <input name="Close Tab1" id="input1" placeholder="Close Tab1">
    <input name="Close Tab2" id="input2" placeholder="Close Tab2">
    <input name="Close Tab3" id="input3" placeholder="Close Tab3">
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi ADyson, Thank you very much for sharing a beautiful solution, that works so well!  However, in this case `<span class="tab"..` is generated from database.  I wonder if there are some ways to generate `data-input="input1, 2,...` dynamically instead of hardcoding:  `data-input="input1, 2, 3, ..."` inside `<span class="tab"`

Comment: Well, if you are generating the HTML for the tabs from the database dynamically using some kind of code, then surely you can change the code so that it adds those values dynamically? It sounds possible, but then I don't know _exactly_ how you're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only thing that associates a tab to an input is the content of the tab so with the least amount of changes to get this to work change your JS to the following:

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("input[name='" + this.innerHTML + "']").hide();

    if($('.tab').is(':visible') == false) {
        $('.message').show();
    }


    var MainTabName = $('#main-tabs input').attr('name');
    var bannerTab = $('.tab:contains('+MainTabName+')');

})
```

But a more "better practice" way of doing it is how ADyson answered.

Comment: This works, but personally I'd avoid writing code which relies on the description/content of the tab, as this is far more likely to change in future, without any thought given to code which might rely on it. Better to rely on IDs or other values which can remain fixed and don't have any other purpose. And also those `name` attributes are not great - spaces in names should be avoided, so I'd be thinking of renaming them anyway.

Comment: @ADyson I totally agree. I updated my answer to show that your answer is more correct.